# Another Olympiad problem about prime number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

p is a prime number Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find $m,n \ \text{and} \ p$ ,such that:

$$\frac{p+m}{p+n}=\frac mn+\frac {1}{p^2}$$

I don't know even how to start I need your help any suggestions please

Comment: First step is to multiply the equation with $(p+n)\cdot n\cdot p^2$

Comment: How this can help (p+m)(n$p^2$)=($p^2$m+n)(p+n)?

Comment: Well, the left side is divisible by $p^2$ , in particular by $p$. What can we conclude ?

Comment: Well $p^2$m+n or p+n are  divisible by p

Comment: That means that $n$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: I appreciate your help I will try to complete thanks for helping me